# JavaScript exception handling - displaying the line number

Tags: javascript, exception, callstack

When catching / handling exceptions in JavaScript, how can I determine what the call stack was when the exception occurred? (and also if possible what the line number was)

```
try
{
    // etc...
}
catch (ex)
{
    // At this point here I want to be able to print out a detailed exception 
    // message, complete with call stack, and if possible line numbers.
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each browser handles this differently, so there isn't a universal way to do it. [This blog post](http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/) has some good code to dump a stack trace for most supported browsers. I don't think there is a good way to provide the line number.

If you're looking to debug one function in particular, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) has a good stack trace function (vis console.trace()).

Comment: That blog is pretty old(2008). There's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/formfeed/2009/03/handling_javascript_exceptions.html).

A way to analyse the available information:

```
try 
{ 
    doInit(); 
} catch(err) 
{ 
    var vDebug = ""; 
    for (var prop in err) 
    {  
       vDebug += "property: "+ prop+ " value: ["+ err[prop]+ "]\n"; 
    } 
    vDebug += "toString(): " + " value: [" + err.toString() + "]"; 
    status.rawValue = vDebug; 
}
```

Comment: Just a note - if you are using node server side this works quite nicely. Upvoted - Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 2):

With *most* errors, you can examine the stack trace, which will include the line and column number of the error location:

```js
try {
  throw new Error('foo');
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
  console.log(e.stack);
  const [, lineno, colno] = e.stack.match(/(\d+):(\d+)/);
  console.log('Line:', lineno);
  console.log('Column:', colno);
}
```

This line 13 is correct, because that is the line in the HTML where the error came from in the response from stacksnippets.net:

[image]

Note that this will *not* work for non-errors thrown, like `throw null` or `throw 'foo'` (which are not recommended for precisely this reason).

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that in JavaScript running under IE it is not possible to capture a stack trace at the point that an exception is caught. According to [this](http://developer.tibco.com/resources/gi/3_4/extensions_to_javascript_exception_handling34.pdf) PDF the only way of getting a stack trace in IE is if you don't handle the exception.